# What event will be called on input AFTER all values of reactive forms are updated

Tags: angular, typescript, events, angular-reactive-forms, ngx-bootstrap

What is correct way in Angular (v.5 or v.6) to emit event **after** specific input of reactive form is changed?

**I've already tried this aproaches**:

1. `(ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)"` (html, basic event)
2. `(bsValueChange)="doSomething($event)"` (html, ngx-bootstrap specific event)
3. basic reactive form solution for one input - subscribe for event (ts) like:

```js
this.reactiveForm.get('inputName').valueChanges.subscribe(
  value => { this.doSomething(value); }
);
```

But nothing works in all situations.

**Testing:**

1. set input value `A`
2. change input value to `B`

**Expected behavior:**

- All `reactiveForm.value` items in `doSomething()` method have **current values**.

**Results:**

**Approach 1**. is not possible to simulate this bug in demo. This is working in [my demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-event-after-change-on-reactive-form) but not working in my large project. After I set first date `A` and then select date `B`, my `"doSomething"` which log actual date of field (and value of $event) in reactive form return `A` for actual field value. Demo working ok, but I don`t know why I can not achieve such behavior in my project.

**Approach 2**. not working at all. This is specific event for ngx-bootstrap, but after I select date `B` I again get date `A` in log.

**Approach 3**. not working at all. This is pure reactive form solution. You can test it on [my demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-event-after-change-on-reactive-form) on the last input. If you type `A` and then `B`, log from `reactiveForm.value['item']`, after you type `B` is only `A`. So even if you subscribe to `valueChanges` event of reactiveForm input, value is not changed.

My question is:
What can I use to catch event for one field of reactive form **after** this reactive form values are updated?

Here is [StackBlitz code DEMO with example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-event-after-change-on-reactive-form)

**PS:** First of all I thought it was a problem of `ngx-bootstrap` extension, but it also does not works for pure input of reactive form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atiris, the answer is: 3.

But see that is different

```
this.reactiveForm.value['testDateE'] //or this.reactiveForm.value.testDateE
```

than

```
this.reactiveForm.get('testDateE').value;
```

Is the reason because if you want to check some in the html you must use the second way. When we send a submit, we submit the reactiveForm.value and there are no problem, Equally if you write {{reactiveForm.value |json}} you'll see the actual values

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. I updated my demo with `.get(ITEM).value` and it looks ok for separate items. And what if I want submit entire form after any change in inputs? I obviously can not use `this.reactiveForm.value` because it contains old values (added to demo). After tests I find that I can use `this.reactiveForm.getRawValue()` (which contains actual version of values) insetad of this.reactiveForm.value...     Do you have any **link to documentation** where I can find more to this difference between `.value` and `.getRawValue()` and in which situations can I use one of this two attributes?

Comment: you can use this.reactiveForm.value to send the values. The common way is make a < form [formGroup]="reactiveForm" (submit)="submit(reactiveForm)">...< /form> and submit(form){ if (form.valid){ console.log(form.value) //<--the values are updated}